# Time complexity of this series

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

How to find the time complexity of below series

[image]

Please tell me is this correct bound or not.

Comment: Can you please tell what is O*?

Comment: There are n choose k items and each item need 2^k time. I seems O*(2^k) is same as O(2^k). But  I could not figure out how it comes O(3^n). Seems I skipped something.

Comment: Because of the way you phrase your comment, I think this is an example to which the answer is known to be true. Am I correct in assuming that, or can the expression have a different value than O(3^n)?

Comment: Also, are you sure if O* is the same as O?

Comment: yes the answer is known as O(3^n) but I am confused how it comes. I do not know the difference between O* and O. But according to the description (in a Thesis) I  seems the author meant to say O* and O same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For complete rigor, the proof must be a little more sophisticated.

Let `f` be the function which is `O*(2^k)`. If `O*(2^k)` is understood in the same sense as `O(2^k)`, then for some `m`, `k≥m => f(k)≤C B(n,k)2^k`. The bounding needen't hold for `k<m`.

Then for `n>m` the summation must be split in two parts,

```
Σ(k=1->n) B(n,k)f(k)
    ≤ Σ(k=1->m-1) B(n,k)f(k) + Σ(k=m->n) C B(n,k)2^k 
    = Σ(k=1->m-1) B(n,k)f(k) - Σ(k=1->m-1) C B(n,k)2^k + Σ(k=1->n) C B(n,k)2^k
    = C' + C 3^n.
    ≤ (C' + C)3^n.
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the correct bound.
According to the binomial theorem, we have:

[image: the picture is here]

Then let x = 1 and y = 2.

Comment: Thank you. I should  think about it.

Answer (score 1):

With little cheating from math exchange to remember the sigma(0,n) nCk = 2^n.

```
(x+y)^n=nC0*x^n*y^0 + nC1*x^n-1*y^1......+nCn-1*x^1*y^n-1+nCn*y^n*x^0  --(1)
```

this  is normal binomial expansion of any equation of above form. Hence on the same terms we can open the given equation

```
(1+2)^n = nC0*1^n*2^0 + nC1*1^n-1*2^1 ......+ nCn-1*1^1*2^n-1 + nCn*2^n*1^0 --(2)
(1+2)^n = 1 + nC1*1^n-1*2^1 ......+ nCn-1*1^1*2^n-1 + nCn*2^n*1^0 --(3)
(1+2)^n = 1+nC1*1^n-1*2^1 ......+ nCn-1*1^1*2^n-1 + nCn*2^n*1^0 --(4)
((3)^n)-1 = nC1*1^n-1*2^1 ......+ nCn-1*1^1*2^n-1 + nCn*2^n*1^0 --(4)
```

Hence given the question is about bounds then -1 can be ignored and given bounds are correct

Comment: @NARAYANCHANGDER you can accept the answer if you feel like.